# picking a FET for 12v use with Arduino

Tags: arduino, 12v

I am working on an Arduino project where I would like to use an output pin to control a 12v load with a mosfet.  I think it should be an n-fet, but am not sure.  I have been looking at specs, and don't know how to pic a fet that will do what I want.  Can anyone point me at a part I could use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How much current do you require? 
For specs you want a FET with a breakdown voltage (BVDSS) above 12V and a current
rating that exceeds your load. A logic-level FET can sometimes be better but it
probably will not matter if your current requirement is only a few amps.
N-channel is usually what you want.

I use the On-Semi NTP65N02 with a 3.3V gate drive level for a current-sink.
TO-220 package and a fairly low Rds(on) at that level.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My current need is less than 3 amps. I would prefer something like a TO-92 package, because I am hoping to fit several on an arduino shield with some other components.

Comment: That may be difficult to find in that small a package. TO-92 has a thermal resistance that is three times that of the TO-220. Higher 
thermal resistance package and a smaller die size makes cooling
difficult (which decreases your current specification).

I would use the Digikey search and select TO-92 package, 12V (and higher) breakdown and see what the results are. At the On-Semi site
the highest current was 500mA for an N-channel FET in a TO-92 package.

(* jcl *)

Comment: Thank you!  That explanation helps a lot.  Can you elaborate on the gate drive level and what Rds(on) is?

Comment: Gate drive is the voltage between the gate and the source (Vgs). The Vgs turns the FET on and off. To get the lowest resistance between the drain and source (Rds(on)) you typically need to drive the FETs at a Vgs of 10V. Driving a FET at a lower Vgs increases
Rds(on). For most applications driving the FET at 3V or 5V 
produces an Rds(on) that is acceptable but you need to review
the datasheet.

The Rds(on) determines the amount of power the FET dissipates and 
your cooling requirements. A low Vgs (and corresponding high Rds(on)) plus a high thermal resistance package (TO92) may be a problem.